# Prevent the phone's speaker from being redirected to the microphone when using a USB-C microphone

Tags: microphone, speaker, usb-c

When I plug in my USB-C microphone, the speaker output (audio sink) gets automatically redirected from the built-in speaker to the USB-C microphone.

How can I set the speaker output (audio sink) to stay on the internal speaker when I plug in the mic?

Comment: Please do mention your Android version and device by [edit] in the question and tags. It matters because it may be version/device specific solution

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. Just to clarify, does the USB-C microphone also has a built-in speaker? Or is it literally "the speaker is redirected to the microphone"?